# Apps crash since migrating to android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio when version 1.0 came out.
This automatically changed the google play services integration (which i use for admob and analytics) to an entry in the app gradle build file.

All my apps that use the play services now periodically crash. Apps that don't use it are working like before.
The crashing apps start up once normally. But when you close them (via recenty opened apps) and then reopen them at a later point, the screen turns black and the app will not respond.

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Do you see something in the logs?

Comment: No. Funny thing is, the logs aren't even showing in logcat when this occurs.

Comment: That is strange, I agree. Maybe connecting with a debugger might help reveal the problem.